# Geometry and Probability:

Tags: probability

Okay I have a test tomorrow and I don't know how to do this, please help me out.

Here is the problem: A bag contains 8 white marbles and 7 blue marbles. Find the probability of selecting 2 white marbles and 3 blue marbles: (hint: use combinations and fundamental counting principle)

It doesn't say it, but I'm sure there are no replacements. I know it's a combination, but I don't know how 3C2 (entered it equals 3) would be the answer because just "3" doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No "3" wouldn't be a very good probability, unless you're a new age statistician...

You need to pick 3 of the 7 blues and 2 of the 8 whites: that can be done in $$\binom{7}{3}\binom{8}{2}$$ where $$\binom{n}{m}=n\text{C} m$$ The *total* possible choices are found by choosing any 5 out of the 15: $$\binom{15}{5}$$ Now divide the two and you have your answer.

Comment: Oooh okay thank you so much that sounds familiar.

Comment: Does the notation make sense? Some people don't write it like that...

Comment: It mostly makes sense. Except I don't know if I should multiply the first two combinations, then divide that number to the third combination (the 15C5 one), or add the first two and do the division.

Comment: You multiply them. That's the fundamental principle of counting - since for each choice you make with the blues, you get certain choices with the whites, you have to take the product (imagine a table of pairs, and multiplying is like finding the "area" of the table taking length x width).

Comment: That helped me so much, thank you. I'll remember the area part on my test tomorrow so I'll be able to do these. Thank you so much

Comment: yep no problem. post any more questions if you have them.